# Python3 to MySQL connection on OSX ...ImportError: Reason: Image not found

Tags: python, mysql, macos, scrapy

I'm currently trying to have scrapy run code that scrapes a website and then writes the data to MySQL. I've been searching for hours on how to resolve my issue, but I get the following error when I run it:

> File
>   "/Users/USER/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py",
>   line 19, in module
>       import _mysql
>
> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Users/USER/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-35m-darwin.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
>
> Referenced from:
>   /Users/USER/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-35m-darwin.so
>
> Reason: image not found

Solutions attempted: uninstalling and reinstalling mysql, installing mysqlclient, installing mysql-connector-c, unlinking/relinking. Would greatly appreciate some help, as I've spent very little of my time actually coding and most of it simply trying to connect python with MySQL. Currently running Sierra 10.12.5.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
brew install mysql
```

if this not works, how about using `mysqlclient` instead of PyMySql?

Comment: I actually started with brew install mysql and assumed that it would just take care of everything. And I tried installing mysqlclient, which is the fork of MySQLdb.

I think the issue revolves around importing MySQLdb, but it doesn't work with Python3. Trying to figure out how to use the fork, mysqlclient, now.

Comment: yeah I do. I think I finally figured out the solution though.

import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb

Not sure why, but this is a work around that allows you to use MySQLdb on Python 3. Appreciate your help!